# How to make first column to grow, while all other columns to have minimal size in MigLayout?

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

The code:

```
public class Try_Grow_01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill, debug", "[fill]5[5]"));

        frame.add(new JButton("one"), "");
        frame.add(new JButton("two"), "");
        frame.add(new JButton("three"), "");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

result is

[image]

i.e. two right cells also grow, while I want them not to.

How to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the first cell grow and fill all available space then you must create the `MigLayout` as follows:

```
frame.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill, debug", "[fill, grow][][]"));
```

[image]

If you want the first cell grow but without fill the available space then you must create the `MigLayout` as follows:

```
frame.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill, debug", "[grow][][]"));
```

[image]

Take a look to page 6 of [Quick Start guide](http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf)